# Get all categories and items in category

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display all the category and the items in those categories.

eg:

```
category 1 name
|Item   | Qty available|
|Item 1 | 6          |
|Item 2 | 1          |
category 1 info

category 2 name
|Item   | Qty available|
|Item 1 | 10          |
|Item 2 | 3           |
category 2 info
```

My Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm not quite sure how to create a view where I can iterate though all the Categories and display a table with all the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def show_categories(request):
    ctx = {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
    }

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', ctx)
```

And the template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
{{ category.name }}
| Item     | Qty available |
{% for item in category.item_set.all %}
| Item {{ item.name|rjust:'3' }} | {{ item.quantity|ljust:'13' }} |
{% endfor %}
{{ category.info }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you add `related_name='items'` to `category = models.ForeignKey(Category)` then you could replace `{% for item in category.item_set.all %}` with `{% for item in category.items.all %}`